# Increment by variable names for a memory address

Tags: c++, variables, naming, memory-address

This may be a very simple answer, I am not sure. I have to give the address of a variable to read in some values in root. I need different variable names because I want to compare them later. Is there a way to all in one step read them into correctly named variables (typed double) that are incrementally named (`Detector_P0`, `Detector_P1`, etc.). This is what I have so far: (I have it working for the `branchName`, but not the `&variableName` in `SetBranchAddress()`). Any advice would be greatly appreciated!!!

```
for (int i = 0; i < nb_det; i++) {

std::string branchVarName = "Detector_P" + std::string(to_string(i));

const char * branchVarNameC;

 branchVarNameC = branchVarName.c_str();

All->SetBranchAddress(branchVarNameC,&???);

}
```

Comment: [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) might be helpful.

Comment: `branchVarNameC` is already an address. `All->SetBranchAddress(branchVarNameC, branchVarNameC);` I have no idea what `SetBranchAddress` does, but you have the `Address Of` operator in there, so I am assuming you want to add the address of `branchVarNameC` in to it. Keep in mind that when your `for` loop exits, the addresses/`char*` will be invalid. You are creating them all in the scope of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to use an array or array like object, such as `std::vector` or `std::array`.

If the size of the array is known compile time, prefer to use `std::array<double, SIZE>`.
If the size of the array is known only at run time, use `std::vector<double>`.

Example using `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<double> data(nb_det);
for (int i = 0; i < nb_det; i++)
{
   std::string branchVarName = "Detector_P" + std::string(to_string(i));
   const char * branchVarNameC = branchVarName.c_str();
   All->SetBranchAddress(branchVarNameC, &(data[i]));
}
```

---

> Yes, with each Detector_P$ variable there are approximately like 5000 numbers associated with each. When I run this file I do know right away how many there Detector_P variables there will need to be. So I would like to somehow create an array for each or at the very list something I can increment over to compare certain indices

It seems like you need a `std::map<std::string, std::vector<double>>` to hold the data.

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<double>> allDetectorData;
for (int i = 0; i < nb_det; i++)
{
   std::string branchVarName = "Detector_P" + std::string(to_string(i));
   const char * branchVarNameC = branchVarName.c_str();
   All->SetBranchAddress(branchVarNameC, allDetectorData[branchVarName]);
}
```

That allows you to read as many or as few `double`s corresponding to a detector and store them in `allDetectorData[branchVarName]`.

However, what concerns me most is how much of this makes sense to you. It will be worth your while to spend time understanding the container class templates in the standard library really well before venturing into using them in your application. I recommend learning about them from [a good textbook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but if I wanted to compare one variable at some index of say Detector_P0 and Detector_P1 wouldn't this approach just simply overwrite the array for each increment in the for loop?

Comment: @LaurenFish, no it won't. The data for Detector_P0 will be saved at `data[0]` while the data for Detector_P1 will be stored at `data[1]`.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh okay that is so cool (sorry I am very inexperienced). So then, if I wanted to compare the Detector_P0[20] and Detector_P3[20] how would I do that if they are saved at the same address?

Comment: @LaurenFish, You seem to indicate that there can be an array of values corresponding to Detector_P0 and also an array of values corresponding to Detector_P1. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, with each Detector_P$ variable there are approximately like 5000 numbers associated with each. When I run this file I do know right away how many there Detector_P variables there will need to be. So I would like to somehow create an array for each or at the very list something I can increment over to compare certain indices.

Comment: I'm pretty certain a vector of vectors should work for you as well- essentially same answer as R Sahu gave but a little more complex. Here's an article with examples: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vector-of-vectors-in-c-stl-with-examples/